# Deserialize list of objects with Jackson via Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, jackson

I am trying to use Jackson via Kotlin to deserialize xml provided by the lastfm api. I had this working in Java with JAXB, and am trying to port it.  Everything works with the exception of unwrapped list fields - Track in the below example. I know that Track data class is working, because if I use `val track: Track? = null` instead of `val track: List<Track>? = null` I do get a valid single Track object.

The error I get is `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of`info.eidson.lastfm.Track`(although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('Flash \Flash Gordon's Theme\&quot;&quot;')
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 205] (through reference chain: info.eidson.lastfm.RecentTracks["track"]->java.util.ArrayList[1])` and I believe it is trying to use the List class as the POJO instead of Track.

I've tried using a regular class instead of a data class with the same result. According to https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-xml-serialization-and-deserialization all that is necessary is to add the `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)` annotation.  I've tried with and without the `@JacksoXmlProperty` annotation and I've tried setting the `useWrapping` on the mapper.

What should I try next?

```
object Api {

    fun getRecentTracks(): RecentTracks {
        val module = JacksonXmlModule()
        module.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);
        val xmlMapper = XmlMapper(module)
        xmlMapper.registerKotlinModule()
        xmlMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
        xmlMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true)
        val params = HashMap<String?, String?>()
        params.put("user", "eidsonator")

        val out = Http.getRequest("user.getrecenttracks", params)
        val stream =  ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray())
        return xmlMapper.readValue(stream, RecentTracks::class.java)
    }
}

data class RecentTracks(
    val user: String = "",
    val page: Int = -1,
    val perPage: Int = -1,
    val totalPages: Int = -1,
    val total: Int = -1,
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "track") 
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    val track: List<Track>? = null
)

data class Track(
    val name: String = "",
    val artist: String = "",
    val album: String = ""
)
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<recenttracks page="1" perPage="50" total="283105" totalPages="5663" user="eidsonator">
    <track>
        <artist mbid="">Rockit</artist>
        <name>Flash \Flash Gordon's Theme\&quot;&quot;</name>
        <streamable>0</streamable>
        <mbid/>
        <album mbid="">Freddie Mercury Rework</album>
        <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Rockit/_/Flash+%5CFlash+Gordon%27s+Theme%5C%22%22</url>
        <image size="small">https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/34s/2a96cbd8b46e442fc41c2b86b821562f.png</image>
        <image size="medium">https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/64s/2a96cbd8b46e442fc41c2b86b821562f.png</image>
        <image size="large">https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/174s/2a96cbd8b46e442fc41c2b86b821562f.png</image>
        <image size="extralarge">https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/300x300/2a96cbd8b46e442fc41c2b86b821562f.png</image>
        <date uts="1578532113">09 Jan 2020, 01:08</date>
    </track>
    <track>
        <artist mbid="">A June &amp; J Beat</artist>
        <name>Irony</name>
        <streamable>0</streamable>
        <mbid>fa542ad6-ed2f-4ce6-ab4c-b2671cd916fa</mbid>
        <album mbid="">Appetizers (Chillhop Presents)</album>
        <url>https://www.last.fm/music/A+June+&amp;+J+Beat/_/Irony</url>
        <image size="small">https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/34s/6aded46748a466920f12854069d9226e.jpg</image>
        <image size="medium">https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/64s/6aded46748a466920f12854069d9226e.jpg</image>
        <image size="large">https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/174s/6aded46748a466920f12854069d9226e.jpg</image>
        <image size="extralarge">https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/300x300/6aded46748a466920f12854069d9226e.jpg</image>
        <date uts="1578531592">09 Jan 2020, 00:59</date>
    </track>
    <!-- 48 more tracks...   -->
</recenttracks>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by the fact that you're trying to take this XML:

```
<artist mbid="">Rockit</artist>
```

and deserialize it to a single string property called `artist`. Same goes for `album`. It's OK with `name` as that doesn't have the `mbid` attribute, but since `artist` and `album` have that attribute, Jackson can't directly deserialize that XML element to a string, as it doesn't know what to do with `mbid`. (You can check this by removing the `mbid` attribute: soon as I did that, the deserialization worked.)

Should the `artist` and `album` properties on `Track` be objects themselves, with a property for `mbid` and another property for the text maybe?

Comment: That fixed it!  I was hung up on "name" since that was the string it was complaining about, and my JAXB implementation ignored the mbid since I didn't try to parse it. I didn't test, but I think adding the `@JacksonXmlText` annotation might have fixed it as well.